# transfer data from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, button, transfer

if I fill state,province and town in first view controller, how to get just town or town and state in another view controller, when I press OK button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhwGq.png

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create a property in the SecondVC.h to receive de text and a property linked to the label in screen:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *townText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *townLabel;
```

After that, in the SecondVC.m, overwrite the "viewWillAppear" method as follows:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.townLabel.text = self.townText;
```

}

Then, in the FirstVC.m, overwrite the "prepareForSegue" method:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
SecondVC *secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
secondVC.townText = self.townTextView.text; // townTextView is the TextView in screen where user writes the town name.
```

}

Don't forget to import the SecondVC.h in the FirstVC.m

Comment: thank you , and how I can import the SecondVC.h in the FirstVC.m ?

Comment: and I have one more warning:  property "townTextView" not found on object of type "ViewController"

Comment: Hi tomas t, to import the SecondVC.h in the FirstVC.m, just write #import "SecondVC.h"  below #import "FirstVC.h" at the top of the class. Then, you will be able to use SecondVC class inside FirstVC.m and you will be able to pass data for one to the other.

Comment: The preperty "townTextView" in the one that refers to the TextView where you write the town name in the FirstVC. Please, check if you have set a different name for it...

Comment: Hey, thank you, but its not working at all :( maybe I did something wrong. I add everything , what did you said, but when I add state , province and town and push OK, in another window is nothing. I add label there with referencing outlet to button OK. but its not working.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way:

```
 Use storyboard's IBOutlet feature. One view controller class can hold a reference to another view controller
 If the code just reference the other view controller
 -(void)clickOK:(UIButton*)
 {
      NSString* town = self.anotherController;
      //do something with town
 }
```

Suggested way:
     Follow the model-view-controller design pattern. Treat first view controller as a data provider

```
Protocal DataProviderDelegate
{
   @required
   -(NSString*)getTown;
   -(NSString*)getState;
} 

 @implementation
  FirstViewController:UIViewController<DataProviderDelegate>
 {

 }

 @declaration
 SecondViewController:UIViewController
 @property(nonatomic, weak)DataProviderDelegate* dataProvider;
```

In the segue, assign first view controller to the second view controller as a delegate

Comment: how can I assign first view controller to the second as a delegate? thank you